# Display image from MySQL in Flask template

Tags: python, mysql, flask

How can I display images in a Flask template whose addresses are stored in MySQL? I am trying to pass the data from the column 'filename' to the template, but the images are not being rendered.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

**Flask code:**

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    # Create cursor
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()

    # Get articles
    result = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM articles")

    articles = cur.fetchall()

    if result > 0:
        return render_template('home.html', articles=articles)
    else:
        msg = 'No articles Found'
        return render_template('home.html', msg=msg)
    # Close connection
    cur.close()
    return render_template('home.html')
```

**Template:**

```
  <div>
    <h1 id=projetos>Projetos</h1>
    <ul class="list-group">
      {% for article in articles %}
        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="article/{{article.id}}">{{article.title}}</a></li>
        <img src={{article.filename}}>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to know where you stored the images then you use:

```
send_from_directory
```

which can be imported from flask with parameters

```
send_from_directory(folder_name, imagefilename)
```

which can be wrapped in a function as

```py
@app.route('/file/<filename>')
def get_image(filename):
    return send_from_directory(folder_name, filename)
```

You use it in templates as:

```html
<img href="{{url_for('get_image', filename='image.jpg')}}">
```

If you want a package to handle assets, i recommend [flask-reuploaded](https://github.com/jugmac00/flask-reuploaded) which is the successor of flask-uploads

For serving static assets in production, this is another story depending on what you use to serve your flask app and the nature and scale of your app.

Comment: Would it work with the directory of the images stored in the MySQL?